# How to increase the existing value in the primary key column without violating constraints?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my MS Access table `myTable`, I have a column `ID` that is of type integer and is the primary key for the table.

I'm in a situation where I need to increase the value of each ID by a certain offset. So, I tried to run

```
Update myTable 
Set ID = ID + [Offset]
```

This command works with very large offsets but ended with errors if the offset was small. The reason seems to be that Access is doing these updates either randomly or in an ascending order which means that when trying to update the value in certain rows, the primary key constraint will be violated. The reason being that in the course of the update, IDs are generated that already exist in the table at that specific time but theoretically would no longer exist if the query finished properly.

Unlike MS Access, SQL Server has a built-in mechanism to deal with that so the statement above would work.

Obviously, apart from just removing the key constraint before the update, the solution would be to force Access to update the field in a descending order, i.e. starting with the highest ID and moving down thus avoiding the possibility of duplicates. However, the following command is not valid in MS Access.

```
Update myTable 
Set ID = ID + [Offset] 
Order By ID Desc
```

*Side note*: This command will work in MySQL.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking to do without removing the key constraint?

Comment: I highly doubt, that you can force it to the `UPDATE` in any particular order. But maybe you could write a procedure that loops through the IDs in an ordered fashion updating one row at a time, thus implicitly forcing an order of processing the rows by having multiple single row `UPDATE` statements. But if this is worth the effort instead of just dropping and recreating the constraint?

Comment: Do it in two sweeps 0) M = Max(id) - Min(id)+1 1) Move all up with M+ offset. 2) move all down with -M  Final: updating a PK is not a good idea

Comment: @joop, thanks, you and Turo had the same idea at the same time. Reason for updating: I'm merging two tables of the same kind that both started at 1 and now have overlapping IDs. Because of FK constraints, I can't just take the data over but have to manage the keys myself and the best way to do that I found so far is with the offset.

Comment: @stickybit thanks for the comment. Deleting the constraint would actually be a bit tricky because it's a linked table. If no other option was left, I'd be best off with the procedure. But I'm glad we found another solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could do it by two Updates:

```
Update myTable Set ID = ID + [Offset] + [HighConstant];
Update myTable Set ID = ID - [HighConstant];
```